# Ajax partial postback not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

```
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1"   OnTick="Timer1_Tick"   Interval="5000" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate>

    <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" name="Data1" value="abc" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am making parital postback with ajax toolkit.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Clicked " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if (Application["Data"] != null)
        {

            string[] s;
            //We know the type inside Application state so we cast it 
        s = (string[])Application["Data"];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string value in s)
        {
            builder.Append(value);
            builder.Append('-');
        }

        Label1.Text = builder.ToString();
        }


    }
```

When i use internet explorer there is no problem,after 5 seconds it do postback.However when i use firefox there is no change.I looked inside with developer tools of firefox and i saw there are problems .

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ScriptResource.axd:5784:50
Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. Graph.aspx:42:39
ReferenceError: Type is not defined ScriptResource.axd:10:0
ReferenceError: Type is not defined ScriptResource.axd:10:0
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined Graph.aspx:55:0
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined Graph.aspx:79:0
```

I tried solutions about adding ScriptResource.axd from web.config but this errors still exists and labels not changing.Why do u think this happens? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i looked in to those errors i saw some adwares were the problem.I used an adware cleaner and these errors are gone.